# Issues while implementing ITestListener interface in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

Hello I am working on Automating a test using selenium webdriver & I am getting below issue when I try to implement the interface ITestListener.

When I implemented the methods using the RightClick -> Source-> Override/implement methods,

the methods are created automatically but without the annotation "@Override" indication. Also, each method has below error "method references to interface default methods are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above" (please see below image).
When I try to add the @OverrideMethod annotation manually, it gives other error "The method onTestStart(ITestResult) of type Listeners must override a superclass method", asking to remove the annotation.
Strangely this worked for other projects in the past & no configuration change has been since then. I tried to match everything with that working project and everything looks same.

I am not sure, what did I miss here. Can you please help me to resolve this issue ?
Also, please note that, the listener tags are also added in testng xml.

```
<listeners>
<listener class-name="trouble.Listeners" />
</listeners>
```

[Eclipse error screen print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQbVt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project execution environment is SE 1.5 now. You need to choose 1.8 or higher
Right click on Java System library on your project folder ->Choose properties .Click on execution environment and select a version 1.8 or above and choose apply and close.

Comment: Thank you Very Much Anu.
I have changed the version to Java SE-15.jre as my system's java version is "15.0.2" 2021-01-19.